# Cant add user picture and thumbnails wont display Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I had been struggling with username change for a while, and last night I felt like I knew enough abt bash to give this a bash. The last time I added a new user it somehow made my main user account not work properly and I immediately deleted it, hence my concern.

I added a temporary user with the adduser command, and gave it sudo permissions, or added it to the sudo group. Then I logged into it and changed my main accounts username with this command:

```
sudo usermod -l newname -m -d /home/newname oldname
```

It seemed to work fine, I got my username changed at last and then deleted the temporary account I had just created. I re mapped a few things with the new username, but I seem to have a few issues:

- Thumbnails wont display anymore. None at all, I have set Nautilus to show thumbnails on all files but still nothing.
- Also, I no longer have a user picture. My pictures folder is intact, but when I go on settings on the GUI, Users, click on the picture to add it, then click select a file, I then select the file I want but the open button at the top right hand corner is not green, and its not clickable. It just wont accept any pictures.
- Another thing is the sidebar has a 'Desktop' folder there that is empty but cant be deleted. The remove option is not available when I right click on it. I have added the `enabled=False` on the `/etc/xdg/user.dirs.conf` file, and also deleted the Desktop folder from the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, cleared cache etc but its still on my sidebar on Nautilus and I cant get rid of it.

Sorry, long message for a first one. Hope anyone can help with any of these issues?

Comment: Did you try creating and editing users from the gnome settings instead of terminal?